# Finding an NFA with 2 conditions

Tags: algorithm, set, boolean-logic, nfa

I am trying to figure out how to write an NFA which can accept the following language with only 6 necessary states:

{w: number of a's is even OR exactly 2 b's} over the alphabet ∑={a, b}
.

Here is an idea for an NFA I had (https://prnt.sc/1ujhoiy) (image provided as link since I don't have the rep to post pictures).

This NFA has the 6 required states and has the needed conditions, but I can't figure out how to OR the 2 conditions together. The aforementioned machine works for simple combinations such as `aa`, `aaaa`, `bb`, but I cant figure out how to connect the two such that inputs `baabaa`, `abbba`, `abba`, `baaab`, `etc...` would come out as true.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://cs.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Comment: The beauty of NFAs is that you can use epsilon transitions and simply decide that the start if you want to go to the "number of a's is even" or if you want to go to the "exactly 2 b's" part. But for that you need to solve these two separate sub-problems first.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson%27s_construction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this as 2 individual NFA first, 1 for each condition. Connect them together from an initial state q0 with a lambda transition to each of them.

Remember that by default in computer science the OR we use is inclusive, where as in english by default OR is usually an exclusive OR. This might help clear up some edge cases when solving.

Comment: Right, that's what I did though [here](https://prnt.sc/1ujhoiy) (ignore q3 being a final state, that was from a prior test). But doing this results in it not accepting strings other than the easy combinations of ``aa``, ``aaaa``, ``bb``, etc...

Comment: The NFA you are showing don't meet the requirements for the language. Take just the first part {w: number of a's is even} this string should accept the character b anywhere in the string as well, as long as there is an even number of a's, but in your NFA q1 and q2 do not accept the character b. Try updating the top portion of your NFA with transition for b such that it accepts aab, baab, baabbbb, etc

Comment: I am having issues trying to see how doing ``aab`` would be possible? Since we have ``q0`` (our initial state) also being a final state, I can't do a transition from it to ``q5`` (a final state) because otherwise, the string ``b`` would then be directly accepted. Here is my updated NFA [here](https://prnt.sc/1ujp0cv)

Comment: I think q4->q3 on a and q3 should be the accept state not q0, that looks like it will work.

Comment: That works perfectly, but there is still an issue of inputs with exactly 2 b's somewhere in the string, even if the above condition doesn't match. Like if we wanted to do ``aaabaab`` the machine rejects the input, even though it should accept it since there are exactly 2 b's present.

Comment: You are correct that following the top lambda transition will not be accepted but remeber for NFA there will be a set of walks not a single one, so if you add the a transitions for the bottom section of your NFA then that will result in an accepted walk and so the input string will be accepted.

Comment: Thank you! I think I figured it out for the bottom part [here](https://prnt.sc/1ujqy95). I think the issue was that I thought about this too hard and tried to get the top and bottom to work together instead of just doing the 2 NFAs separately. Thanks for the help!